# UITabBarController's moreNavigationController and Navigation Bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I have UITabBarController with 5+ view controllers (each embedded in its own UINavigationController). Some of them hides navigation bar, and when I navigate to these view controllers from "More" tab and back, navigation bar is hidden for "More" tab. As for me this behaviour is very unexpected. Is there some fix?

Here is screenshot:
[image]

Comment: do you try to set [self.moreNavigationController.navigationBar setHidden:false];

Comment: Yes, I tried to setHidden: false in tabBarController(tabBarController: UITabBarController, didSelectViewController viewController: UIViewController). No effect

Answer (score 0):

user3237732:

I had a similar issue with 'UITabBarController' with its own 'UINavigationController' and navigating between two different views that were connected with "to" and "back" buttons.

Every time I pressed the Back button, I found either the navigation bar or tabBars hidden. 
By trial and error what fixed this was (1) Going into the Atributes inspector in storyboard (2) Goto 'Bottom Bar' line under "Simulated metrics" and change 'inferred' to another option like 'Translucent'.

This fixed the issues.

Comment: That's very strange since all Simulated metrics do is help you to check your interface in Interface Builder and have no impact on xib and storyboard files